# Nickname search results in Everything Vertical SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, people-search, result-source, promoted-results

SharePoint 2013 provides us the nice, built-in feature of `Nickname` search on the People vertical. It works really well. As seen in below screen shot.

[image]

Now, on the `Everything` vertical first `do not show people result`, so for that I have created a `Promoted result source using query rules within Everything vertical` which brings the people result if we search for actual names. As seen in below screen shot.

[image]

But when on same Everything vertical if I search Nicknames it does not come through (Refer to below screenshot). Is there anything else I need to do apart from creating a result source?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nickname matching (and phonetic name matching) are passed with the query from the web part or REST request. You can't configure it in the Query Rule. Thinking about it though...you could create a page that does the necessary query and return it as a Promoted Result, but it won't work quite like a result block.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219499.aspx

From that page:
People search uses fuzzy name matching. Fuzzy name matching includes phonetic matching of names, and can't be disabled.

Promoted results are also not people search.

Hope that helps